# What's the size limit for text_area_tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the max size limit for `text_area_tag` in Rails 3/4? We put an 4-digit id array with 577 elements and it blows off in development:

```
Request-URI Too Large
WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge
```

Here is the view code:

```
    <%= form_tag export_file_onboard_user_accesses_path(format: 'csv'), method: :get do %>
       <%= text_area_tag 'record_ids_', models.page(params[:page]).per_page(1000).pluck('id') %>
       <%= submit_tag 'CSV' %>
    <% end %>
```

33 elements have no error.

Comment: This is not a text area limitation, its URI length limit. Try to use POST instead of GET

Comment: You are right. Just thought about this as well. Need to use method: :put. Will mark as answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to deal with `WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge` error:

first - use other HTTP method than GET (POST, PUT, and so on)

second:

Add a file called `webrick.rb` file to the `config\initializers` directory.

```
if defined?(WEBrick::HTTPRequest)
  WEBrick::HTTPRequest.const_set("MAX_URI_LENGTH", 10240)
end
```

As for me, first one is better

Comment: `<%= form_tag export_file_onboard_user_accesses_path(format: 'csv'), method: :put do %>` works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [2kb to 8kb limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request) on HTTP GET requests, which is one of the reasons Dropbox is [switching some APIs to POST that would otherwise be GETs](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/03/limitations-of-the-get-method-in-http/).

It's good to keep actions canonical with what they are doing, but in this case I would recommend changing the verb to something else (a POST, perhaps).

Comment: The question you are referring has a great link, which I guess is more appropriate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers